# How to create simple C# Binary socket server (Not WCF!) (Simplest Way To Open and Use a Socket in C# ?)

Tags: c#, sockets

How to create simple C# Binary socket server  (Not WCF!)

### Who knows the Simplest Way To Open and Use a Socket in C# (Not with WCF)?

---

What do I need? I need -

- Open Source Libs
- Tutorials
- Blog posts/Articles

---

Vote!) one who will take at least (0+25) votes wins

Comment: Its a contest for publicly approved answer) the point is I do not know the correct answer. No one is going to count lines. So let's select correct answer using votes (this question do not suppows wrong answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard .NET [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28VS.71%29.aspx) classes -- they are trivial to use and do what you want.

If you want to use open source only, the Mono implementation of these classes works perfectly.

Answer (score -3):

Probably use winsock.

here is what google found:

[Winsock with c#](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3312)

And there is a lot more out there...

Comment: Don't use an activex control! Theres built in classes.

Comment: Have a look ato System.Net.Sockets namespace

Comment: He asked for the simplest way.

Comment: Um, its not any simpler with the built in classes?

Comment: Actually it (link to some forum post) looks like simple and good explanation. But ACTIVEX... Not Open Source... not Cross platform... and sum of code lines will probably lose to TcpClient and TcpListener ...